# For each group find observations with max value of several columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Assume I have a data frame like so:

```
set.seed(4)
df<-data.frame(
    group = rep(1:10, each=3),
    id = rep(sample(1:3), 10),
    x = sample(c(rep(0, 15), runif(15))),
    y = sample(c(rep(0, 15), runif(15))),
    z = sample(c(rep(0, 15), runif(15)))
)
```

As seen above, some elements of `x`, `y`, `z` vectors take value of zero, the rest being drawn from the uniform distribution between 0 and 1.

For each group, determined by the first column, I want to find three IDs from the second column, pointing to the highest value of `x`, `y`, `z` variables in the group. Assume there are no draws except for the cases in which a variable takes a value of 0 in all observations of a given group - in that case I don't want to return any number as an id of a row with maximum value.

The output would look like so:

```
group  x  y  z
  1    2  2  1
  2    2  3  1
 ...  .........
```

My first thought is to select rows with maximum values separately for each variable and then use `merge` to put it in one table. However, I'm wondering if it can be done without `merge`, for example with standard `dplyr` functions.

Comment: With `data.table` you might try `setDT(df)[,lapply(.SD,function(x) id[which.max(x)]),by=group,.SDcols=c("x","y","z")]`

Comment: Please use `set.seed` when using functions such as `sample` and `runif`. You may try `library(dplyr); df %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise_at(vars(-id), funs(which.max))`

Comment: does the first row in expected output ` 1 5 2 4` mean that group 1 has highest value for id 5 in columns X, for id2 in column y and for id 4 in column z? if yes, then are you expecting just 2 rows of output? then why the continuation dots in the expected output?

Comment: @Aramis7d The number of rows in the output should be equal to a number of groups. I used the dots because I expect the output to have 10 rows in this example.

As for the first question, for each group I want to obtain three values, derived from `id` column, which point to maximum values of `x`, `y`, `z` in a given group. I'm not sure if that's what you were asking. Also, please note that I changed the example so that expected output matches the code generating the example.

Comment: @Sotos Added `set.seed` as per suggestion, thanks. Also thanks for the code, it seems to be working. Why don't you post it as an answer? I'd be happy to approve it.

Comment: Except that it does not account for the situation when all elements are zero in one column for a certain group.

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer Also, I think it doesn't work properly if the `id` column isn't in increasing order for each category. In my original problem that is sometimes the case. I'll change the example to account for this.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my proposed solution using `plyr`:

```
ddply(df,.variables = c("group"),
.fun = function(t){apply(X = t[,c(-1,-2)],MARGIN = 2,
function(z){ifelse(sum(abs(z))==0,yes = NA,no = t$id[which.max(z)])})})

#   group  x  y  z
#1      1  2  2  1
#2      2  2  3  1
#3      3  1  3  2
#4      4  3  3  1
#5      5  2  3 NA
#6      6  3  1  3
#7      7  1  1  2
#8      8 NA  2  3
#9      9  2  1  3
#10    10  2 NA  2
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution uses `dplyr` and `tidyr`. Notice that if all numbers are the same, we cannot decide which `id` should be selected. So `filter(n_distinct(Value) > 1)` is added to remove those records. In the final output `df2`, `NA` indicates such condition where all numbers are the same. We can decide whether to impute those `NA` later if we want. This solution should work for any numbers of `id` or columns (`x`, `y`, `z`, ...).

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df2 <- df %>%
  gather(Column, Value, -group, -id) %>%
  arrange(group, Column, desc(Value)) %>%
  group_by(group, Column) %>%
  # If all values from a group-Column are all the same, remove that group-Column
  filter(n_distinct(Value) > 1) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  select(-Value) %>%
  spread(Column, id)
```

Comment: @docendodiscimus Thank you for your suggestion. I have replaced that line with `filter(length(unique(Value)) > 1)`.

Comment: @docendodiscimus By the way, the only situation I can think of when `filter(Value != mean(Value))` fails is if there are missing values in the original `df`. But checking if there is only a single unique value stills works better.

Comment: @docendodiscimus Thanks. Then please check my current solution to see if it works for the OP's data.

Comment: The filter statement looks good now. Since you're using dplyr you _could_ also use `n_distinct` but that's not necessary of course.

Comment: @docendodiscimus Thanks. `n_distinct` is more concise. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stick with just `dplyr`, you can use the multiple-column `summarize`/`mutate` functions. This should work regardless of the form of `id`; my initial attempt was slightly cleaner but assumed that an `id` of zero was invalid.

```
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-id), 
            # If the row is the max within the group, set the value
            # to the id and use NA otherwise
            funs(ifelse(max(.) != 0 & . == max(.),
                        id,
                        NA))) %>%
  select(-id) %>%
  summarize_all(funs(
    # There are zero or one non-NA values per group, so handle both cases
    if(any(!is.na(.)))
      na.omit(.) else NA))
## # A tibble: 10 x 4
##    group     x     y     z
##    <int> <int> <int> <int>
##  1     1     2     2     1
##  2     2     2     3     1
##  3     3     1     3     2
##  4     4     3     3     1
##  5     5     2     3    NA
##  6     6     3     1     3
##  7     7     1     1     2
##  8     8    NA     2     3
##  9     9     2     1     3
## 10    10     2    NA     2
```

Comment: Your solution generated output different than the expected one. You may want to sort id before running your codes.

Comment: @ycw, I think that is due to Jean's edit that updated the order of the ids. The first group now has a max for x and y on id 2, and the max for z on id 1.

Comment: add `arrange(id)` after the `group_by(group)`, then you can get the same output as the expected one. However, please be aware that the number your solution reported is row index, not the actual `id` number.

Comment: Bah, you're right @ycw-- and I was looking right at that! It was an artifact of trying to fix it to not require 0 as an invalid id. I didn't want to use arrange, since I worked off the assumption that there could be more than one of the same id in a group. Funnily enough, the actual fix didn't even require modifying the associated comment, since the comment explained what I meant to do, not what I did. Thanks!